# Attempt to assign property of non-object in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following Laravel code which receive data from an API and store them on a database.

```
$sample = Sample::findOrFail($id);
$new_sample = $request->except('filename');

if ( $request->file('filename') ) {
     if ( $sample->filename ) {
           Storage::disk('documents')->delete($sample->filename);
     }
     $file = $request->file('filename');
     $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $new_sample->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
     Storage::disk('documents')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
}

if (!$sample->update($new_sample)) {
     throw new HttpException(500);
}
```

I have the following error `Attempt to assign property of non-object` and I found that by commenting out the line where I assign the filename, the error doesn't appear again.

`$new_sample->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;`

So, I guess the problem is here. I tried also with

`$new_sample['filename'] = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;`

but then it doesn't store the filename.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there is no file in Request object.

This is because you're using the wrong method for checking file. Use [`hasFile()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) method. So you need to change this:

```
if ( $request->file('filename') ) {
```

To this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
```

Comment: There is a file on the request... This is part of the http body I send: `------WebKitFormBoundaryb1BbiXbbXXILD1Tr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="plank-challenge.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf`